Somewhy jupiter tests work in one IntelliJ IDEA project and do not work in another
I was doing a student assignment "task3" in Intellij IDEA and found out that professor sent us a new tests file. I downloaded it from the university website.
I replaced Part2 with the new version of file and redacted it. Then I copied the project out of IDE and named it "task3v2". At some moment tests stopped working. I deleted all task3 versions and unpacked the project from .zip again - it does not work. In morning it worked, now it does not.
Even more: In other projects test work
they work in task2
and do not work in task3
I tried File/Invalidate Caches and Build/Rebuild project, nothing helped. I also tried downloading and unpacking project stub again - it did not help.

looks like your dependencies are missing. Can you please try to reload them with maven?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In the Maven tool window, try to click the Reload All Maven Projects , and better provide the full project source code in Google Drive or GitHub site.
